# How do I access a view controller from AppDelegate.m during a background refresh

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to implement background refresh in my app. I have a method `refreshMessages` that is inside one of my `UIViewControllers` (I am using a `UINavigationController`). I need to access this controller from `AppDelegate.m`.

Usually I would do something like this:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [self.window.rootViewController navigationController];
```

to get the navigation controller and I can then access them from there. But surely this won't work now. The app is in the BACKGROUND and no window is showing. Any thoughts on how to get around this? Thanks!

Here is my background refresh:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application
performFetchWithCompletionHandler:
(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {



    NSLog(@"Doing the background refresh");

    UINavigationController *navigationController = [self.window.rootViewController navigationController];
    NSLog(@"Number of controllers is %d", [[navigationController viewControllers] count]);
    //There are zero controllers?!!! Must be because no window is showing
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right. The `window` will be `nil` since it will no longer be in the view hierarchy.

A cheeky solution would be to hold the reference of the view controller in the `AppDelegate` by creating a property in it. You can assign this when the application goes to the background by subscribing to the relevant notification in the view controller.

**Edit: Code added**

*In your `AppDelegate.h`*

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) YourViewController *yourViewController;
```

*In YourViewController.m, somewhere in `viewDidLoad`*

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(appWillResignActive:) name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:nil];
```

*`appWillResignActive`'s implementation*

```
-(void)appWillResignActive:(id)sender {
    YourAppDelegate *delegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    delegate.yourViewController = self;
}
```

*In your completion handler*

```
[self.yourViewController refreshMessages]
```

Also, make sure you remove the observer once the view controller is deallocated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, actually just discovered you can access is in AppDelegate.m like this: UINavigationController *navigationController=(UINavigationController *)[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController]; using keyWindow instead of accessing the views that aren't show because it is in the background.